# iOS App isn't able to find framework header files

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I have a Cocoa Touch framework created in Obj-C, I have built it for simulator as well as for arm7, 7s, 64 and it is a fat framework.
After adding this framework to the test project by dragging, when I try to add header file through import it autocompletes, yet Xcode is unable to locate those files and returns an error.

I have tried adding search paths as well but to no avail, Xcode just doesn't find those files.

I have made all those headers public while creating framework, have tested with an embedded test app it works

Here are Xcode images 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: @SwiftArchitect file not found is the error in Xcode

Comment: @SwiftArchitect check screen images

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536379/include-headers-from-added-frameworks-on-xcode, referred this link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29322894/5362916 tried checking with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: No problem in finding header but I get another error about missing architecture]

```
AdGateMediaiOSSDK.framework/AdGateMediaiOSSDK, missing required architecture x86_64 in file

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AdGateMedia", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After connecting an iPhone and disabling the bitcode, project compile and built.

Comment: no, on simulator it does not work because the architecture x86_64 is missing when you built the framework.

Comment: Yes i guess so , i think i forgot to aggregate the simulator build

Comment: So all I did is that i created a new project, downloaded and unachieved your framework and dragged and dropped the framework file with copy option selected for the main app target and then imported the header as shown in the screenshot. You can try enabling architecture for simulator and if you want also enable the bitcode.

Comment: I was able to get rid of those errors too, but then saw theses simulator build errors, thanks anyways

Comment: I am still not sure which step cured the issue , i will create a new test app and check again

Comment: But now library doesn't load , error it gives is dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AdGateMediaiOSSDK.framework/AdGateMediaiOSSDK
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E8F169C5-0F32-4966-97AF-D51604FE4C13/SDkTestIos1.app/SDkTestIos1
  Reason: image not found" it seems it wasn't able to find binary for the framework

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092886/image-not-found-error-while-using-custom-framework

Comment: Thanks , found out that the framework wasn't added to "Embedded binaries" section now its working

Comment: Thanks for taking detailed look into the issue

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the header files you want 'public' when making your framework.

In Xcode:

1. Select the header file you want to expose (project navigator)
2. Select 'file inspector' right hand side in Xcode.
3. Locate the section 'Target Membersip'
4. Make sure that your framework is selected
5. After the name of your framework there is a selectable drop down meny.
6. select 'public' out of public/private/project.

re-compile the framework and re include it. Now you see the header file you made public.

Comment: I have done that already, also this framework works fine when i create a test app along with it in same workspace

Comment: check images attached

Comment: you state: "I have made all those headers private while creating framework" you need to make them 'public'.

Could you share the framework for me to see?

Comment: Can't believe I didn't check this myself. Wish I could give you 10 up votes. Solved my issue and I'm back in business! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set "Header search path" in Build Settings

Comment: Yep tried that already , what I wonder is Xcode is able to autocomplete but compiler unable to find it , adding to header search path doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

Do what ***Anders Cedronius*** told ☝, and then, if the problem persist:

7. Right click on [*YOURIMPORTED.framework* -> *Show in Finder*] (and the finder window will apear)
8. Close Xcode (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>)
9. On the Finder window: Delete the imported *YOURIMPORTED.framework*
10. On the Finder window: Paste the *RECOMPILED.framework*
11. Open your project on Xcode, and Build/Run it!

Done :D

Answer (score 0):

When you drag the framework to your project,do remember you have selected the option ["copy items if needed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J12QB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this issue when I was using the library provided by a third party.And you should have noticed that the related .framework file was marked with a question mark, which might not be recognized by the XCode and appeared to be the same issue as I met.

My solution was right clicked the .framework file and deleted it, and then added the original file again until the question mark was disappeared.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

It would be like this:

```
#import "AdGateMediaiOSSDK.framework/AdGateMediaiOSSDK"
```

Hope this help.